# Get + 4 days to date

Tags: php, date

i have got date in format like this:

```
$datum = date("d.m.Y", strtotime(osC_DateTime::getShort($this->_order->getInvoiceDate())));
```

it shows: 15.04.2012
how can i get there + 4 days?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct one

```
$date = osC_DateTime::getShort($this->_order->getInvoiceDate());

$datum = date("d.m.Y", strtotime("$date + 4 day"));
```

Comment: This seems like to get a really high value!

Comment: At last we got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newdate = date("d.m.Y", strtotime ( '+4 day' , strtotime ( $datum ) )) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$shortDate = osC_DateTime::getShort($this->_order->getInvoiceDate());

$datum = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($shortDate +4 day));
```

Comment: I +1 it, tried to edit it but the edit is so short it wont let me save it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add number of seconds to generated timestamp.

```
$timestamp = strtotime(osC_DateTime::getShort($this->_order->getInvoiceDate()));
$datum = date("d.m.Y", $timestamp + 4 * 24 * 60 * 60); // add 4 days
```